# Building a dynamic querytask 4.11

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo

Learning the js api i tried to make a querytask that will query a layer and update graphics on change.

I think the problem is in my success("succ") function.

I made this codepen:

https://codepen.io/segev-salman/pen/joBwyW

in the 3.28 version of the api I saw a code example building an array and a for loop inserting features into a graphic from the querytask reault, but the 4.11 doc says that querytask returns a graphic so does that mean i can throw the result straight into a new graphic layers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had a ton of problems some require inconsistency , some bad syntax but mostly used 3.x function instead of 4.x.
 codepen.io/segev-salman/pen/rgmaGr